# dropdownlist index mapping to table index and show it to gridview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm stuck with this code.  Kindly help me out with this.

What I am trying to do is: I have dropdownlist which has number of days (1,2,3 etc), and what I am trying to do is I have to map these days to my database, and show it to gridview.

But problem is I think I have a problem in my mapping, and when I select day 1, I get an Error message: `Data is Null.  This method or property cannot be called on Null values`.

If I choose any day other than 1, it shows the values in the gridview; however I want a single value corresponding to dropdownlist index matches to table index.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = true;
        double dbstan_minmoist = 0.0;
        double dbstan_mintemp = 0.0;
        double dbstan_sunshine = 0.0;
        double dbstan_capacity = 0.0;
        double dbcurr_minmoist = 0.0;
        double dbcurr_mintemp = 0.00;
        double dbcurr_capacity = 0.0;
        double dbcurr_sunshine = 0.0;

        if (ddl.SelectedIndex >0)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedIndex);

            int c = 1;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source");
            con.Open();
            var strquery = "select Min_Moisture,Min_Temperature,Sunshine,Field_Capacity from tbl_Standard_values";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (c== id)
                {
                    dbstan_mintemp = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("Min_Temperature"));
                    dbstan_minmoist = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("Min_Moisture"));
                    dbstan_sunshine = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("Sunshine"));
                    dbstan_capacity = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("Field_Capacity"));
                    break;

                }


                else
                {
                   c=c+1;

                }



            }
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=");
            con1.Open();
            var strquery1 = "select distinct Min_Moisture,Mim_Temperature,Sunshine,Field_Capacity from tbl_Cornels_Development";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(strquery1, con1);

            int d = 1;

            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr1.Read())
            {

                if (d == id)
                {
                    dbcurr_mintemp = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Mim_Temperature"));
                    dbcurr_minmoist = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Min_Moisture"));
                    dbcurr_sunshine = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Sunshine"));
                    dbcurr_capacity = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Field_Capacity"));
                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                   d=d+1;
                }
            }
            //first case
            if ((dbcurr_mintemp < dbstan_mintemp) && (dbcurr_minmoist < dbstan_minmoist) && (dbcurr_capacity < dbstan_capacity) && (dbcurr_sunshine < dbstan_sunshine))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('LightIrrigation');", true);

            }
            //second case
            else if ((dbcurr_mintemp < dbstan_mintemp) && (dbcurr_minmoist < dbstan_minmoist) && (dbcurr_capacity < dbstan_capacity) && (dbcurr_sunshine > dbstan_sunshine))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('LightIrrigation');", true);

            }
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView2.DataSource = dr1;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            con.Close();
        }

        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please select a day');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to follow the question and the code, but after a some reading, I think your issue may be that these lines:

```
var strquery1 = "select distinct Min_Moisture,Mim_Temperature,Sunshine,Field_Capacity from tbl_Cornels_Development";
...
dbcurr_mintemp = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Mim_Temperature"));
```

should read:

```
var strquery1 = "select distinct Min_Moisture,Min_Temperature,Sunshine,Field_Capacity from tbl_Cornels_Development";
...
dbcurr_mintemp = dr1.GetDouble(dr1.GetOrdinal("Min_Temperature"));
```

that is, you have Mim instead of Min.

Comment: thanks for the reply!! but this is not a problem. becoz Mim_temprature is column name of different table.

Comment: What line of code throws the exception / error?  Can you post the full exception / error?